# Elixir: загрузка модуля в iex

Tags: elixir

Как загрузить модуль из файла в [iex](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html)? Что-то вроде [:load](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/loading-source-files.html) в GHCi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запустить iex с указанием файла, есть много способов

```
1. iex "file.ex"

2. iex -r "file.ex"

3. iex
   iex> c "file.ex"
```

больше вариантов https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html
и `iex --help`

Comment: Третий вариант - то, что нужно. Только скобки нужны. Спасибо!

Comment: скобки не нужны, в эликсире любую функцию с аргументами можно записать без скобок) если подошел третий вариант, то наверно пригодится еще `r ModuleName` для перезагрузки уже скомпиленного модуля

Comment: Действительно. Спасибо за уточнение!